# AEM/CQ: Removing toolbar actions Delete/Add on a parsys in Touch UI Mode

Tags: aem

I am automatically rendering some components inside a parsys. I would not like these components to be removed or any other component added to this parsys. Only Toolbar Actions "Insert" and "Delete" should be disabled on the parsys. What is the best approach for resolving the issue?

Regards,
Sagar

Comment: get some help on asking question at https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: By parsys, do you mean you have a custom container component? OOTB parsys feature can only be changed if you overlay it which is not recommended (causes lots if issues with target, campaign integrations). You would normally create a custom component to control this behaviour of internal components.

Comment: Thank you @i.net. Yes. I will be creating a custom component to implement this. However, just wanted information on how specifically do I achieve the  removal of Toolbar Actions "Insert" and "Delete" in this toolbar.

Comment: Is this classic or touch UI?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `cq:editConfig` node:

> read more here: https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/develop/platform/custom-nodetypes.html

add the file `_cq_editConfig.xml` to your component:

```
<jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
    cq:actions="[text:Component Name,-,edit]"
    cq:dialogMode="floating"
    cq:layout="editbar"
    jcr:primaryType="cq:EditConfig">
</jcr:root>
```

the important bit here is `cq:actions="[text:Component Name,-,edit]"`
normally you would add `insert` and `delete` but they are removed per your requirement.